# cocos2d GL_SUBTRUCT problem when using CCRenderTexture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My game needs to implement night vision effect. I'm using a CCRenderTexture as a mask, and I plan to draw the visible areas onto the mask by using [rangeSprite visit];

However, it need GL_SUBTRUCT mode. I searched cocos2d's codes, but found nowhere the macro is used. Does it mean cocos2d do not support this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this? I have the same problem, and am approaching it currently by using a `blendmode` like this:

```
[light setBlendFunc:ccBlendFuncMake(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO)];
```

...whereas `light` is a sprite I paint onto my `CCRenderTexture`, which gets laid over the screen.